# Windows 7 always shows me an exclamation mark on the shutdown button

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, windows-update

I have a Windows 7 Brazilian Portuguese box, but from the beginning of the year it always shows me an exclamation mark on the shutdown button, even if there are no updates.

I think I need to rollback some updates, but I not sure which and even not sure if this is the right thing to do in order to fix it up.

Could anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: Is that just on the Shutdown button or any other wheres? There are many ways to change Shutdown button caption and i think that a program did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset your Windows Update state as such:

- Stop the Windows Update service.
- Stop the Background Intelligent Transfer (BITS) service.
- Head to `c:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution`
- Delete all contents.
- Start the Windows Update service.
- Run Windows Update.